# Load PHP file with document.createElement()

Tags: src, createelement

How could I make this work?  I want to load a php file like this:

- Click button.
- Call Javascript function.
- In Javascript function create an img with src file.php.

This should force the loading of the php.  Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d;

function callSave() {
 alert ('calling');
 if (d) document.body.removeChild(d);
 // d = document.createElement("script");
 d = document.createElement("img");
 d.src = "savepages.php";
 //d.type = "text/javascript";
 document.body.appendChild(d);
}

</script>
```

Then in savepages.php I do another alert to verify that the php is called and it isn't.  Here is the savepages.php.

```
<?php
echo "alert('from the php');"; 
?>
```

The alert from the php doesn't happen.  Is there a different element type that will force loading of the php?  I don't have ajax installed, so I need a workaround like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why and what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Trying to call alert inside the source you are supplying for an image will not work. If you just want an image then your php needs to set the right headers and return only image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the better way to handle this. There is this simple code that explains how to call a javascript function from a form event and from that javascript function load a PHP file. The code found at http://daniel.lorch.cc/docs/ajax_simple/ is also given here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var http = false;

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
  http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function validate(user) {
  http.abort();
  http.open("GET", "validate.php?name=" + user, true);
  http.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
  }
  http.send(null);
}
</script>

<h1>Please choose your username:</h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" onkeyup="validate(this.value)" />
  <div id="msg"></div>
</form>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
function validate($name) {
  if($name == '') {
    return '';
  }

  if(strlen($name) < 3) {
    return "<span id=\"warn\">Username too short</span>\n";
  }

  switch($name) {
    case 'bob':
    case 'jim':
    case 'joe':
    case 'carol':
      return "<span id=\"warn\">Username already taken</span>\n";
  }

  return "<span id=\"notice\">Username ok!</span>\n";
}

echo validate(trim($_REQUEST['name']));
?>
```

Comment: The other option is to have the PHP file in the form action <FORM name="pagesform" action="savepages.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> ... </FORM>.  The file savepages.php is called when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d;

function callSave() {
 alert ('calling');
 if (d) document.body.removeChild(d);
 d = document.createElement("iframe");
 d.src = "savepages.php";
 document.body.appendChild(d);
}

</script>
```

Comment: It makes sense, but this doesn't call the php alert.

Comment: Looks like an iframe is more appropriate.  Does anyone know what else could be wrong with this code that could explain why the php isn't called.  I don't try to do an alert from there anymore.  I only try to do a text echo.

The savepages.php now has:

    <?php
    echo "from the savepages php"; 
    ?>